# ExpandedList view not works properly in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have fetch Comments via Json parsing in Facebook and i create Expanded list view to see all comments of the post but it cant expand in layout. please help me to fix this.
this is my XML layout

```
 <ExpandableListView
     android:id="@+id/expandableListView1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:groupIndicator="@null">
 </ExpandableListView>
```

And my code

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    int s=ConstantsValues.commentsResponse.get(position).size();

    View view=convertView;
    LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_expandablecomments_parentgroup, parent,false);
    TextView tv1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView_GROUP);
    tv1.setText("Click hee to see " +s+" comments");
    tv1.setPadding(100, 0, 0,0);
    return view;
}
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    HashMap<String, Object> hashmap= ConstantsValues.commentsResponse.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
    View view=convertView;
    position=childPosition;
    LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_expandable_comments, parent,false);
    ImageView imv=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.Imageview_profipic_commentsShow);
    TextView tv1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView_Name_CommentShow);
    TextView tv2=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView_Comments_show);
    imv.setImageBitmap((Bitmap)hashmap.get("Image"));
    tv1.setText((String)hashmap.get("UserName"));
    tv2.setText((String)hashmap.get("CommentsFull"));

    return view;
}
```

Comment: What happened ..What is the problem

Comment: @Pragnani the whole comments im fetching is not expand in it.

Comment: check is there any exception or an error in the logcat..if so post that..

Comment: Why android:groupIndicator="@null" ?

Comment: @user2230793 that is to hide arrow mark icon in that

Comment: @Pragnani No there is nothing Error arised and Feed also came properly with profifepicture, name, comments.

Comment: @ManojKumar ok...Than try Nandu answer.. override onGroupExpanded method

Comment: @Pragnani Actually function work perfectly but UI only problem

Comment: @Pragnani In my XML layout already i have one List view for wall post of FB. In that layout itself i have Expandable list view below that. if i press parentgroup text it not extend to show already has comments. Got it

Answer (score 0):

Use this code....Hopefully it may help you...

```
@Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition){
        //collapse the old expanded group, if not the same
        //as new group to expand
        if(groupPosition != lastExpandedGroupPosition){
            accordion.collapseGroup(lastExpandedGroupPosition);
        }

        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);           
        lastExpandedGroupPosition = groupPosition;
    }
```

Comment: HI for me functions works fine and got Feed also but UI only not get it. In my XML layout already i have one List view for wall post of FB. In that layout itself i have Expandable list view below that. if i press parentgroup text it not extend to show already has comments.

Comment: @ManojKumar spend some time for reading this two links sure you will get it....http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html       and       http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want default expanded group then do this:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = super.getGroupView(groupPosition, isExpanded, convertView, parent);
    ExpandableListView eLV = (ExpandableListView) parent;
    eLV.expandGroup(groupPosition);
    return v;
}
```

That is use **expandGroup**()